# jQuery activate function when user scrolls to specific section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using progressbar.js to animate path fills, which is going quite well, however I have ran into a issue where the animation / function is playing as soon as the user loads the page.

The plan is for the function to run when the user scrolls to the section where its contained.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/y12e8uks/1/

I have tried using `$(window).scroll` event, however im having a few issues implementing that into the existing function.

Any help would be great on this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Path('#heart-path', {
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#container').offset().top,
       hH = $('#container').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
       $('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            $(this).append("%");
        }
    });
});
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This seems to be definitely a step in the right direction, however the svg line fill animation and percentage still run when the page is loaded, when I scroll onto the heart the numbers start to decrease back down to a random number, eg. 7